# Blender Addon save Hotkey Preferences

Tags: python, add-on

I have for my Blender 2.8 addon 2 keyboard shortcuts that I add to the AddonPreferences:

[image]

In the **init** file I use this code to draw them:

```
class FC_AddonPreferences(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        col = layout.column()
        kc = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
        for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
            km = km.active()
            kmi.show_expanded = False
            col.context_pointer_set("keymap", km)
            rna_keymap_ui.draw_kmi([], kc, km, kmi, col, 0)
```

And here is how I add them

```
addon_keymaps = []

def register():
   # add keymap entry
   kcfg = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
   if kcfg:
       km = kcfg.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')

       kmi = km.keymap_items.new("object.fc_immediate_mode_op", 'P', 'PRESS', shift=True, ctrl=True)

       kmi_mnu = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu", "Q", "PRESS", shift=True)
       kmi_mnu.properties.name = FC_Main_Menu.bl_idname
       kmi_mnu.active = True

       addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
       addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi_mnu))
```

This works, but when I save the settings and reopen Blender the changes that the user made are gone and reset to default.

What am I missing? Thx!

Comment: I have a similar issue since Blender 2.8 for which I opened an issue: https://developer.blender.org/T59113

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a fairly late response but I'm going to post my findings anyways in case someone else gets stuck like we did.

From my own testing, the problem comes from this line

```
km = kcfg.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
```

For some reason Blender doesn't permanently save keymaps to **3D View**. I switched it to 'Object Mode' and now it works fine. Code looks like this now:

```
km = kcfg.keymaps.new(name='Object Mode', space_type='VIEW_3D')
```

I'm pretty sure other modes like 'Mesh' work too but I haven't tested it.
Sorry its not a full answer. I myself am not sure why this happens but I thought I'd share regardless.

EDIT: Another test with a different script did allow me to save a keymap to 3D View which stayed after restarting Blender. This is quite odd honestly since the code is mostly the same. Maybe its a conflict with another addon? Regardless, if you take anything away from this, it is that you should try different modes to save the keymaps to.

Comment: Hi man, this doesnt work for me, I get an error then in the Preferences dialog. And still saving with name = "3D View" doesnt persist. Issue is still open : https://developer.blender.org/T60766

Comment: Damn, I guess this is a bug after all :/
Does it still happen if you switch space_type to = 'EMPTY'? Just for testing purposes.

Sorry I couldn't help :(

Comment: Same, not persisted